# looking to # 50 being a win using edge case

Tags: python

I have a small game and I would like 50 to produce a win but still keep the code as is how would  use an edge case

```
import random

roll = input('Press Enter to Spin the Wheel or Type Stop!')

while roll == "":
    prize = random.randint(0, 100)
    print ('Youre number is ', prize )
    if prize < 50: 
     print ('Sorry, you didnt win. Try again')
    if prize > 50: 
     print ('Congratulations! Youre a winner!')

    roll = input('Press Enter to Spin the Wheel or type Stop!')

if roll == 'Stop' or roll=='stop': 
    print ('Thank you for playing')
else:
    print ('Well, so long!')
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are checking for numbers strictly greater and strictly less than 50. You need to change one of them be less strict and allow 50 to count as well:

```
if prize < 50: 
 print ('Sorry, you didnt win. Try again')
if prize >= 50:                 # use >= to test if prize is greater than *or equal* to fifty
 print ('Congratulations! Youre a winner!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `prize` is **equal to** 50:

```
if prize == 50:
    print ('Congratulations! Youre a winner!')
else:
    print ('Sorry, you didnt win. Try again')
```

Comment: Question states 50 is an edge case for a win, implying 51~100 are also loses.

Comment: @Brian Oh, indeed! I guess I need some coffee :) I've just updated the answer

Comment: Oh, my answer seems to be what yours used to be (before you were prompted to edit). I guess I think your first version was better, but I guess the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the help I liked it